# Recall and precision metrics for multi class classification in tensorflow keras

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

We had a problem to classify three categories. And we would like to figure out the recall, precision metrics for the each class.
We found there are built-in precision and recall metrics in `tf.keras.metrics`. But the metrics seem only work for binary classification.
In our model, the last layer is Dense layer with active function 'softmax'. The loss function is `sparse_categorical_crossentropy`, as we used class label for y.

```
output = Dense(3, activation='softmax')(attention_mul)
model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy, optimizer='Adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

The output of the prediction result is a vector of the probability of the each class, e.g. [0.3, 0.5, 0.2].To get the class label, we need to apply `np.argmax()` for the prediction results. While the built-in recall and precision metrics accept class label for the inputs.

```
m = tf.keras.metrics.Recall()
m.update_state([0, 1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1, 1])
m.result().numpy()
```

Are there any solutions to get precision and recall metrics, and monitored in every epoch of the training?

Answer (score 2):

There is a reason why Precision and Recall in Keras are not available for a multi-class classification problem. Since the metrics are computed batch-wise, the results for these two metrics may not be accurate.
Actually Keras had an implementation of precision and recall, that decided to remove for this very reason.

However, if you really want to, you can create custom metrics for precision and recall and pass those to compile.

From [Keras GitHub](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/1c630c3e3c8969b40a47d07b9f2edda50ec69720/keras/metrics.py), the removed metrics:

```
def precision(y_true, y_pred):
    """Precision metric.
    Only computes a batch-wise average of precision.
    Computes the precision, a metric for multi-label classification of
    how many selected items are relevant.
    """
    true_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true * y_pred, 0, 1)))
    predicted_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_pred, 0, 1)))
    precision = true_positives / (predicted_positives + K.epsilon())
    return precision


def recall(y_true, y_pred):
    """Recall metric.
    Only computes a batch-wise average of recall.
    Computes the recall, a metric for multi-label classification of
    how many relevant items are selected.
    """
    true_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true * y_pred, 0, 1)))
    possible_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true, 0, 1)))
    recall = true_positives / (possible_positives + K.epsilon())
    return recall
```

Add the metrics to `compile`:

```
model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy, optimizer='Adam', metrics=['accuracy', precision, recall])
```

This way you can monitor the two metrics at each epoch like you asked.

Comment: Great thanks! But the code might only work for binary classification, class 0 and 1. Our problem is to classify for three category, class label 0, 1, 2. In tf keras doc, Recall() and Precision metric can passed the class_id argument: tf.keras.metrics.Recall(
    thresholds=None, top_k=None, class_id=None, name=None, dtype=None
), which could get the metric for each category 0,1,2.

Answer (score 1):

There is keras metrics project https://github.com/netrack/keras-metrics. However, it did not maintained and is out of the date for the current version of Tensorflow, e.g. 2.7.
Inspired by the project, I finally figured out the solution: we could customize the metrics functions. Here are the code:

```
    def recall(y_true, y_pred, c):
        y_true = K.flatten(y_true)
        pred_c = K.cast(K.equal(K.argmax(y_pred, axis=-1), c), K.floatx())
        true_c = K.cast(K.equal(y_true, c), K.floatx())
        true_positives = K.sum(pred_c * true_c)
        possible_postives = K.sum(true_c)
        return true_positives / (possible_postives + K.epsilon())


    def precision(y_true, y_pred, c):
        y_true = K.flatten(y_true)
        pred_c = K.cast(K.equal(K.argmax(y_pred, axis=-1), c), K.floatx())
        true_c = K.cast(K.equal(y_true, c), K.floatx())
        true_positives = K.sum(pred_c * true_c)
        pred_positives = K.sum(pred_c)
        return true_positives / (pred_positives + K.epsilon())

    def recall_c1(y_true, y_pred):
        return recall(y_true, y_pred, 1)

    def precision_c1(y_true, y_pred):
        return precision(y_true, y_pred, 1)
    
    def recall_c2(y_true, y_pred):
        return recall(y_true, y_pred, 2)

    def precision_c2(self, y_true, y_pred):
        return precision(y_true, y_pred, 2)
```

We could use precision_c1, recall_c1 to indicate the precision and recall metrics for the category 1, and precision_c2, recall_c2 for the category 2. More categories could also support by passing the class_id value c to the function recall() and precision().
Here are the sample output during the model training:

```
Epoch 2/2000
24/24 - 35s - loss: 1.1322 - accuracy: 0.0675 - recall_c1: 0.9962 - precision_c1: 0.0676 - recall_c2: 0.0054 - precision_c2: 0.0402 - val_loss: 1.1263 - val_accuracy: 0.0357 - val_recall_c1: 1.0000 - val_precision_c1: 0.0344 - val_recall_c2: 0.0000e+00 - val_precision_c2: 0.0000e+00 - 35s/epoch - 1s/step
Epoch 3/2000
24/24 - 35s - loss: 1.1321 - accuracy: 0.0678 - recall_c1: 0.9873 - precision_c1: 0.0679 - recall_c2: 0.0178 - precision_c2: 0.0876 - val_loss: 1.1254 - val_accuracy: 0.0382 - val_recall_c1: 0.8761 - val_precision_c1: 0.0346 - val_recall_c2: 0.2432 - val_precision_c2: 0.0948 - 35s/epoch - 1s/step
```